Unable to boot into gui mode
It happened during an upgrade to v 24.04 and now I'm unable to boot into Gui mode and it shows
[    0.084915] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
/dev/sda5: clean, 579229/26476544 files, 38972830/105903872 blocks
[    32.512467] Bluetooth:  hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x2
[FAILED] Failed to start logrotate.servive - rotate log files.

I think it's stuck in the gui boot. Idk what happened
But I can go into CLI mode pressing ctrl+alt+f2.
Before there was an error saying failed to start virtualbox.service right after the Bluetooth error and I removed virtualbox from my pc.Still didn't fix it though

Those info messages not actual errors would not cause the no boot. You of course have a good back up of the system before doing the upgrade?

Well my pc is backed up on my drive and there is nothing on there.ik the messages aren't errors but I thought someone might relate and help. Also I can access and see my files in CLI mode.Can you try recommending a way to fix it without me having to reinstall the os if not I'll reinstall.
